# Use CSS class in another CSS file

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have Asp.net Core 5.0.1 app with multiple MVC views. I also have a CSS file, generated by an app. I want this file to be unmodified (as it will be changed in future using same app). I want separate CSS file, which styles certain elements (eg `input` or `button`) to be styled using classes from the generated CSS. I dont want to write class on each `input` or `button` etc element (there are 35 views needs to be styled).

For example if generated file has class `dx-theme-text-color` I want a CSS file which has something like `input { color:.dx-theme-text-color}`

How can I achieve this?

*To clarify: the question is - how to use a class from one CSS in another by name not copy/pasting values etc*

Comment: Would the name `dx-theme-text-color` change everytime or stay the same?

Comment: it will change thats the problem. its part of the "theme" which is re-gen every time

Comment: I didn't mean the class value. I meant the name of the CSS class. Anyway, I posted my answer. Even the name of the CSS class `dx-theme-text-color`, you should only need to change at one place.

Comment: no. name stays the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only think of `@extend` from SASS:

```css
.dx-theme-text-color {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

input, button {
    @extend .dx-theme-text-color;
}
```

[image]

Comment: its been 25 yrs of web dev history and such a simple feature is not readily available.. i am disappointed :)

Comment: I agree, but things are imrpoving a lot so there might be something new that works tomorrow :). Most people are using SASS nowthesedays. If your app that generates the theme CSSs can generate SASS instead, you can do a lot of awesome stylings with just few lines of codes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css variables.

define css variavles in global scope:

```css
:root {
    --my-custom-color: #000;
}
```

use variables in every css file like this:

```css
.my-element {
    color: var(--my-costum-color)
}
```

You can also use css pre-proccesors like sass(scss), less and etc.

Comment: the colours are defined in the generated file. it will be overriden each time i use theme editor app. if I wanted to modify that file, instead of using variable etc i would just write my own styles there.. the question is - how to use a class from one CSS in another by name not copy/pasting values etc.

Comment: @boppity-bop it is not possible to inheritance classes in plain css. you should use sass for this purpose

Comment: just write it as an answer then.. i am surprised though.. why are they called cascading style sheets?